# Showing class values for different class types in one row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't know how to write query in sqlite that would from this table:

```
image_id | feature_id | feature_val
_________|____________|____________
  12     |    1       |     41
  12     |    2       |     82
  12     |    3       |     75

  74     |    1       |     23
  74     |    2       |     35
  74     |    3       |     72
```

Returned a result table:

```
image_id |  feature_1_val  | feature_2_val | feautre_3_val
_________|_________________|_______________|_______________
  12     |       41        |      82       |       75
  74     |       23        |      35       |       72
```

We can assume that number of image features is constant and equals 3.
I would be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The process of turning rows into columns is called `pivoting`.  It's best done client-side.  For example, Microsoft Excel has extensive support through Pivot Tables.

But it's not impossible in SQL.  Here's one example using the `max(case(` trick:

```
select  image_id
,       max(case when feature_id = 1 then feature_val end) as feature_1_val
,       max(case when feature_id = 2 then feature_val end) as feature_2_val
from    YourTable
group by
        image_id
```

Comment: I very similiar code but without "max" and it did not work properly. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints outlined in the question, you can create an inelegant, but workable approach using subqueries:

```
SELECT it.image_id,
       (SELECT feature_val FROM ImageTable WHERE ImageTable.image_id = it.image_id AND ImageTable.feature_id = 1) AS feature_1_val,
       (SELECT feature_val FROM ImageTable WHERE ImageTable.image_id = it.image_id AND ImageTable.feature_id = 2) AS feature_2_val,
       (SELECT feature_val FROM ImageTable WHERE ImageTable.image_id = it.image_id AND ImageTable.feature_id = 3) AS feature_3_val 
  FROM ImageTable AS it
  GROUP BY it.image_id
```